# How to make Bootstrap container auto for height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie for JS/CSS and also Bootstrap. And I got a problem for the Bootstrap's height. In general, when the content is too much, the different parts overlay.

My webpage is based on the Cover template (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples/cover) of Bootstrap.
When I added many content in the `<div class="inner cover"></div>` block of https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/examples/cover/index.html
The layout becomes horrible and chaotic:
[image]

While the correct layout is: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

How can I make the container height auto, so that the height is adjusted according to the content length? Thanks for your attention and help!

Comment: Have you set the position of header to fixed? Please make a jsfiddle for that.

Comment: @UmerJaved Thanks for your suggestion. Going to make a jsfiddle. PS: not only the header, also the footer has some issue.

Comment: @UmerJaved I made the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wxgd1mj6/ . It shows correctly in a small screen, such as mobile and jsfiddle. But in the larger screen in desktop, it becomes chaotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this css :

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this .css you have this part :

```
/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
```

So, for me, the problem is your custom cover stylesheet isn't in the right place. Hopes this help you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am a newbie. Actually I read the css briefly before posting the question. However, I do not know where is the issue and how to fix. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Yep. Just copy past the content of the cover.css (in the bootstrap sample) into <style></style> of your page and you will have the same result.

Comment: Got the problem! THX! However, the issue comes.

With the "position: fixed;", the page with lots of content will overlay. BUT without the "position: fixed;", the page with a few content looks "too flat". Which properties could be used to solve it? Thanks!